# Alarm clock application in iphone and android using phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, xcode, jquery-plugins, cordova

While developing an iphone and android application using phonegap,came to a point where i have to build a alarm clock functionality like the image.

[image: Alerm Clock]

I am setting the alarm using Jquery which is running properly when user is in app. But it's not working when the app is closed or the phone is in sleep mode.

Is there any way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a phonegap equivalant, but in Android you'll need to use the AlarmManager for the alarms.  This will launch your application when the alarm is triggered.  You'll also need to set a WakeLock when you have active alarms.  Otherwise the device can go into sleep mode and you won't get the alarms:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

The Android Alarm uses the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK and only when there are active alarms.

Comment: Android has that nice [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP) that can wake up the phone, setting a permanent wakelock will just waste ur batteries.

Comment: The AlarmManager will handle trigger the application to activate if it's not running.  But it won't wake the phone if it goes into sleep mode.  The WakeLock is required for that.